# Show that in the $R^n$ with the 2-norm metric space $d$, $B_d (x,r) = x + rB_d (0,1)$, for all $x \in R^n$ and $r>0$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Show that in the $R^n$ with the 2-norm metric space $d$, $B_d (x,r) = x + rB_d (0,1)$, for all $x \in R^n$ and $r>0$

My first question is, does this make sense if we aren't talking about a vector space? why?

How would you prove this problem? I'm also not understanding why $r>0$ and not $r ≥ 0$. Is there no point where $B_d (x,r) = x$?

Answer (score 1):

**First**, in the equality $B_d (x,r) = x + rB_d (0,1)$ addition and scalar multiplication are used. So, it is not obvious for the equality to be meaningful outside of a vector space.

**Second**, regarding the proof. If $y \in B_d (x,r)$, you have $\Vert y-x \Vert < r$ hence $y= x + r(\frac{1}{r}(y-x))$ hence $y \in x + rB_d (0,1)$ as $\frac{1}{r}(\Vert y-x \Vert) < 1$. Conversely for $z \in B_d (0,1)$ you have $x+rz - x= rz$ hence $z + rB_d (0,1) \subseteq B_d (x,r)$

**Lastly**, if $B_d$ denotes open balls then indeed $B_d(x,0)$ is empty as $y \in B_d(x,0)$ would mean $\Vert y-x\Vert <0$ and a norm is non negative.

Comment: For the proof, how have you shown it's for all r >0?

Answer (score 0):

1. There are metric spaces which aren't linear. However, if you want to formulate the statement $B_d(x,r) = x + rB_d(0,1)$ you need a space with an addition and a scalar multiplication. Whether the statement is true, depends obviously on the space.
2. The usual definition of ball is
   $$ B_d(x,r) = \{ y \in \mathbb R^n \mid d(x,y) < r \}. $$
   For $r =0$ the set $B_d(x,r)$ is empty. I know no author who ever consider the empty set as a ball. However, the empty set is open!
3. As for the proof of $B_d(x,r) = x + rB_d(0,1)$, that is in fact true in any normed induced metric space. Notice that
   $$ \| y - x \| < r \iff \left\| \frac{(y-x)}{r} - 0 \right\| < 1. $$